# Why an underscore in `float.is_integer`, but not in `str.isnumeric`?

Tags: python, naming-conventions, pep8

It appears that [`float.is_integer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) is the only "is" method with an underscore in its name among built-in types in Python. [Examples that don't](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) include an underscore: `str.isalnum`, `str.isalpha`, `str.isdecimal`, `str.isdigit`, `str.isidentifier`, `str.islower`, `str.isnumeric`, `str.isprintable`, `str.isspace`, `str.istitle`, `str.isupper`.

Any clues as to why?

By [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), I would expect all these names to include an underscore. But practicality beats purity ([PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)), so omitting the underscore in frequently used and short names makes sense. However, both naming conventions at once seems as a consequence of backward compatibility (with the `logging` module as the canonical example).

Comment: Maybe because `float.is_integer` is a more recent addition (as of 2.6), long after PEP8 has been established? The `str` apis were probably there since the beginning and were not changed due to compatibility reasons (though it probably could have in 3). `float.fromhex` could also potentially be renamed, I'm sure there's more cases to be found throughout the standard types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [similar question](https://bugs.python.org/issue29088) has been asked on the Python bug tracker:

> Compare `isinstance`, `issubclass`, and `islower` to `is_integer`, `is_fifo`, and `is_enabled`. In Python 3.6, of all the names in the standard library starting with `is`, I count 69 names with the underscore and 91 without. It seems better to pick one way or the other and stick with it. I would recommend using the underscore, for legibility.

And the answer (from R. David Murray, a Python core developer) there was:

> Yep, that would be nice.  But Python has evolved over time, and we must maintain backward compatibility.  The names are what they are.

Given the numbers in the question it seems like `is_integer` is not the only method with an underscore.